# Access Databases and ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, database, ms-access

I apologize if this question is not appropriate; however, I personally do not have Microsoft Access installed on my machine, so I am not able to test it first hand.

To my understanding, an Access database is a local database that is stored on a personal machine rather than a remote server. I am in the planning phase of a project will involve two basic interfaces - one for a regular user and another for the admin who will be running reports and the like. Personally, I would rather just use either an SQL Server or MySQL database all the way and just write some stored procedures or whatever is necessary to do the reporting.

However, the end administrative user may want to use Access. With this is mind, I am curious how I should approach the problem. As I stated earlier, I am not familiar with Access databases; however, I do not believe it is realistic to host one on a server and allow many users to access this database through a web interface. Is this correct or not? If it is possible, what is the general procedure for setting such an application up?

If not, what are my alternatives? Is there an easy way to sync a remote SQL server or MySQL database with Access database hosted on one's PC?

Thanks much.

Comment: You could simply use Access as the front-end and SQL server as the backend. You can run your stored procedures from Access as well. You can in fact use Access in that way, I believe the limit is 255 concurrent read/write operations. If your company has SharePoint or its part of a subscription, you should look at Access Web App's.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not believe it is realistic to host one on a server and allow
>   many users to access this database through a web interface. Is this
>   correct or not?

You have a number of options including hosting the access database in a network folder.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Ways-to-share-an-Access-desktop-database-03822632-da43-4d8f-ba2a-68da245a0446

See also "Using Access Data on an ASP.NET Web Page"
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/445z2s49(v=vs.100).aspx